# How not to use a variable as global when multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, multiprocess, pathos

My task is to build the right application architecture and use multiprocessing in Python. I will note right away that I use the `multiprocess` library, which uses `dill` serialization.

I have 2 files: `initialization_manager.py` (which I want to run as the main one) and `worker_manager.py` (with the `WorkerManager` class).

In `initialization_manager.py` I initialize and configure the `Logger` and would like to use it throughout the project. Therefore, here I create an instance of `WorkerManager` and pass the `logger` to its constructor.

In `WorkerManager`, I want to use multiprocessing, and I would like the `logger` to be global (but this is becoming a bad architecture, it seems to me). What should I do in such a situation to use one `logger`?

The code below does not work because multiprocessing creates a copy of the logger (since I use 5 processes, it will create 5 different loggers). I have tried to narrow down the problem I am facing as much as possible.

File `worker_manager.py` (with the `WorkerManager` class, where I want to use the `logger` already created at the beginning of the project)

```
from multiprocess import Pool


class WorkerManager:
    def __init__(self, logger):
        self.logger = logger

    def start_workers(self):
        numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        with Pool(5) as pool:
            pool.map(self.perform_task, numbers)

    def perform_task(self, number):
        self.logger.debug(f"Number = {number}")
```

File `initialization_manager.py` (the file that I run and in which I declare the `logger` that I want to use in all other classes):

```
import logging
import sys

from worker_manager import WorkerManager

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s . %(name)s . %(levelname)s . %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)


def start_project():
    worker_manager = WorkerManager(logger)
    worker_manager.start_workers()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_project()
```

After launching the `initialization_manager.py` there are no messages in the console. But I would like to get the following:

```
[date] . worker_manager . DEBUG . Number = 1
[date] . worker_manager . DEBUG . Number = 2
[date] . worker_manager . DEBUG . Number = 3
[date] . worker_manager . DEBUG . Number = 4
[date] . worker_manager . DEBUG . Number = 5
```

Comment: you switch to error logging `self.logger.debug` -> `self.logger.error` it works, so there's probably some problem with the log level configuration or logger configuration

Comment: @Macattack If you change `self.logger.debug` to `self.logger.error` in `WorkerManager`, the following messages will indeed appear in the console:
`Number = 1
Number = 2
Number = 3
Number = 4
Number = 5`.
But if `perform_task()` outputs `print(self.logger)`, then I will see `<Logger __main__ (WARNING)>`, that is, messages of the `DEBUG` level should also be output.

Comment: if you add this: `print(self.logger.getEffectiveLevel())` you'll see `30`, which you can correspond to `logging.WARNING` log level
Logs only get printed if their level is >= the current log level. DEBUG (10) is less than WARNING (30) so they don't display. 
I don't know exactly what the fix is to get this configured right, but, debug statements aren't getting printed because of the logging level.

Answer (score 0):

> In WorkerManager, I want to use multiprocessing, and I would like the
> logger to be global (but this is becoming a bad architecture, it seems
> to me). What should I do in such a situation to use one logger?

Not just for multiprocessing, but the best practice is to separate the logging setup from the main code. ie, configure the logging from a file (json, yaml, ...) and use [dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig). This removes a lot of headaches caused by misconfiguring the loggers and helps you concentrate more on the actual problem of the main code.

> The code below does not work because multiprocessing creates a copy of
> the logger (since I use 5 processes, it will create 5 different
> loggers). I have tried to narrow down the problem I am facing as much
> as possible.

Yes, the problem quickly gets complicated with multiprocessing.

Logging works just fine only if you use `fork` method to create a new process.
With `spam` method, the logger must be passed into the child processes. Since the logger is not **picklable**, only its name got passed and branch new loggers with the same name were created in the child process as you have noticed. With the **default** params, these loggers only output to the console with level `WARNING` or above.

If you want to go down this rabbit hole of logger and multiprocessing, the standard docs already have a nice [example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) to boost your start. The basic idea is to serialize the log messages coming from all child processes and use a central process/thread to do the actual logging.

Then, to have a useful logger, you still have to make all processes use the same log config, and even log uncaught exceptions (crash) in the child processes, too.

Or use [logger_tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt/tree/master), configure your logging once, and just focus on your main application for the rest of your time.